# Не могу полностью выйти из гугл аккаунта в андроид приложении

Tags: java, firebase

В приложении сделан вход по google account через сервис Firebase. Проблема в том, что когда я выхожу из аккаунта при помощи следующей команды:

```java
 FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

но потом при нажатии на кнопку login у меня нет выбора гугл аккаунтов, а автоматически заходит в последний который использовался, как это исправить?
P.S. помогает только переустановка и сброс данных.